# ReactJS xlsx add data rows in template file and preserve cell formatting, column formatting, and data validations

Tags: reactjs, excel, formatting, xlsx, sheetjs

I have my ReactJS app where I want to be able to insert rows in to an existing excel file.

The reason for the template is that this file contains headers with style formatting. Also, I have data validations (e.g., lists, input message, etc.).

```
    const response = await fetch("/pending_submissions.xlsx");
    const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();

    const workbook = read(buffer, { type: "binary" });
    const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[SHEETS.BATCH_SUBMISSIONS];

    // Insert the data into the copied sheet
    utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, rawData, { origin: "A2" });

    writeFile(workbook, "Pending Submissions.xlsx");
```

This is my current code. It works, it inserts creates the file with the new data and I am able to download it.

However, the cell formatting and data validations are lost and not preserved.

I am using **^0.18.5 xlsx**